# How ot proof that of $1-1=0$ and $(-1)x = -x$ holds?

Tags: proof-writing

Is there any proof that $1-1=0$ and that $(-1)x=x$?

These proofs should be created using only multiplication, addition and several basic rules like $a+x=0$, $a+0=a$, $1a=a$ etc.

Comment: Well, both rely on the fact, that there is a unique additive inverse to any number $x$, called $-x$ with the propertythat $x+(-x)=0$.Then the first statement is a definition and the second one can be shown by evaluating $x+(-1)x$.

Comment: What exactly to you mean by $-1$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: First of all you need to establish what your axioms are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you define to be your axioms, but yeah, there are proofs.

The usual way to go about things is to first define addition as a commutative operation with a unit, and to *define* that unit to be called $0$. Then you define multiplication, and you define the unit of multiplication to be equal to $1$.

Subtraction, $a-b$, is usually defined as $a-b = a+(-b)$, and for each $a$, $-a$ is defined as the unique solution to the equation $a+x=0$.

Using this, you can already see that

- $1-1 = 1+(-1)$ (by definition of $-$), and
- $1+(-1)=0$ (by definition of $-1$).

---

You also define as your axioms that addition and multiplication are distributive, meaning that $(a+b)c=ac+bc$. Using this, you can show that  $0\cdot x + 0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x$ and then, using the definition of $0$, get the equation $0\cdot x+0\cdot x = 0\cdot x$ which means (after we add $-(0\cdot x)$ to both sides of the equation) that $0\cdot x = 0$ for all $x$.

Then we can go for $(-1)\cdot x$ like so:

- $(-1)\cdot x + x = (-1)\cdot x + 1\cdot x$ (by the definition of $1$)
- $(-1)\cdot x + 1\cdot x = (-1+1)\cdot x$ (by distributivity)
- $(-1+1)\cdot x = 0\cdot x$ (by the definition of $-1$).
- $0\cdot x=0$ (we already proved that.

So, altogether, we have the equation $$(-1)\cdot x + x = 0$$ which means, by definition, that $(-1)\cdot x = -x$.

Comment: Distributive rule with (1-1) is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. Now that I'm looking at it, I don't quite understand how you infered (-1)x = -x from (-1)x+x=0. Is it that trivial? Because to me it seems like a subtraction

Comment: @Gillian $-x$, by definition, is the unique number that, when you add it to $x$, gives you $0$. If I add $(-1)\cdot x$ to $x$, I get $0$. Therefore, $(-1)\cdot x$ is a number that, when I add it to $x$, gives me $0$. Therefore, $(-1\cdot x) = -x$.

Comment: @Gillian Or in equations, $y=-x$ if and only if $y+x=0$. Since $(-1)\cdot x + x = 0$, we can conclude that setting $y=(-1)\cdot x$ causes $y$ to satisfy the equation $y+x=0$, therefore, by definition, $y=-x$.